# Складні числівники на -тисячний, -мільйонний, -мільярдний

Tags: правопис, числівники

В Правописі 2019 року, в параграфі 38 "Складні числівники" є пункт 2:

> 2) складні порядкові числівники, останнім компонентом яких є **-сотий**, **-тисячний**, **-мільйонний**, **-мільярдний**: *девʼятисо́тий*, *трьохсо́тий*;
> *двохти́сячний*, *десятити́сячний*, *пʼятсоттридцятити́сячний*; *чотирьохмільйо́нний*, *пʼятдесятимільйóнний*, *шістдесятипʼятимільйо́нний*;
> *семимілья́рдний*, *трьохмілья́рдний*.

А саме, в пункті 2, є два приклади `шістдесятипʼятимільйо́нний` та `пʼятсоттридцятити́сячний` побудова яких мені незрозуміла.

1. Складний числівник `шістдесятипʼятимільйо́нний` має три частини:

- `шістдесяти́` – `шістдеся́т` в родовому відмінку;
- `пʼяти́` – `пʼя́ть` в родовому відмінку;
- `мільйо́нний`

2. Числівник `пʼятсоттридцятити́сячний` складається з наступних частин

- `пʼятсо́т` – `пʼятсо́т` в **називному** відмінку;
- `тридцяти́` – `три́дцять` в родовому відмінку;
- `ти́сячний`

Звідки в `пʼятсоттридцятити́сячний` взявся називний відмінок?
Це помилка в правописі? Якщо це помилка, то не може ж бути `шістдесятпʼятимільйо́нний`?
Чи є яксь правило щодо цього і тут все вірно?

---

UPD. Також в правописі є "**пʼятдесяти**мільйо́нний" замість "**пʼятидесяти**мільйо́нний"

Comment: "пʼятдесятимільйо́нний" - це не помилка.